# Data structure for sparse insertion

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

I am asking this question mostly for confirmation, because I am not an expert in data structures, but I think the structure that suits my need is a **hashmap**.

Here is my problem (which I guess is typical?):

- We are looking at pairwise interactions between a large number of objects (say N=90k), so think about the storage as a sparse matrix;
- There is a process, say (P), which randomly starts from one object, and computes a model which may lead to another object: I *cannot* predict the pairs in advance, so I need to be able to "create" entries dynamically (arguably the performance is not very critical here);
- The process (P) may "revisit" existing pairs and update the corresponding element in the matrix: this happens a lot, and therefore I need to be able to find and update as fast as possible.
- Finally, the process (P) is repeated millions of times, but *only requires write access* to the data structure, it *does not* need to know about the latest "state" of that storage. This feels intuitively like a detail that might be exploited to improve performance, but I don't think hashmaps do.

This last point is actually the main reason for my question here: is there a data-structure which satisfies the first three points (I'm thinking hash-map, correct?), and which would also exploit the last feature for improved performance (I'm thinking something like buffering operations and execute them in bulk asynchronously)?

*EDIT:* I am working with C++, and would prefer it if there was an existing library implementing that data structure. In addition, I am limited by the system requirements; I cannot use C++11 features.

Comment: You should tag C++ as well. As for your question, I think the answer goes beyond pure data structures. Your hashmap gut is correct I think, you just need to embed your map in a system that is aware and takes advantage of your last property.

Comment: @Rerito I just added the tag :) Thank you for your feedback, I'm just hoping there might be a solution ready in some scientific library; this seems like a problem that would be common in physics for example.

Comment: When you say "only requires write access", do you mean it may go `data.update(i,j,v)` where the value v because the new value, rather than summing a previous value?

Comment: How many pairs of objects will P typically consider?

Comment: Whatever you choose, write a class which exposes just the required methods (possibly just `set`).  Then you can write P in terms of that class, and tinker with the internals to your heart's content.  Are you allowed to use [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html)?  If so, that will do most of the work for you.

Comment: @MartinBonner The operation is essentially `data.update(i,j,v)` where the value `v` is added to the existing value at index `(i,j)`. Typically, (P) will define only 10% of all possible (ordered) pairs (so ~90k^2/10). However this increment does not need to be executed upon-call, execution can be deferred. We can use boost; is there a particular data structure that would fit? I was also thinking about [sparsehash](https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash), although like hash-maps, it does not exploit the last property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

class Data
{
    boost::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>,double> map;

public:
    void update(int i, int j, double v)
    {
        map[std::pair<int,int>(i,j)] += v;
    }
    void output();  // Prints data somewhere.
};
```

That will get you going (you may need to declare a suitable hash function).  You might be able to speed things up by making the key type be a 64-bit integer, and using `((int64_t)i << 32) | j` to make the index.

If nearly all the updates go to a small fraction of the pairs, you could have two maps (`small` and `large`), and directly update the `small` map.  Every time the size of `small` passed a threshold, you could update `large` and clear `small`.  You would need to do some carefully testing to see if this helped or not.  The only reason I think it might help, is by improving cache locality.

Even if you end up using a different data structure, you can keep this class interface, and the rest of the code will be undisturbed.  In particular, dropping sparsehash into the same structure will be very easy.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I am getting going with `tr1/unordered_map` instead for the moment, but I think the usage is very similar to `boost::unordered_map`? I am not familiar with cache locality, but I will give a go to using two maps as well, and post an update comment FYI when I do :)

Comment: Cache locallity:  You *really* need to understand this for performance work.  Memory is not fast.  It is a slow peripheral to the CPU.  There are typically two levels of cache between the CPU and real memory.  If you keep having to read data from actual memory, you will run like a drain.  Edit: Wrong link.